# How is Feshbach resonance potential term physically produced?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, atomic-physics

In Feshbach resonance model, a 2$\times$2 potential term with space dependent diagonal and non-diagonal terms is written 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
V_{11}(\mathbf{r}) & V_{12}(\mathbf{r})\\
V_{21}(\mathbf{r}) & V_{22}(\mathbf{r})
\end{array}\right).$$
How are these terms physically produced? An example of Feshbach resonance that can be taken is of two atoms far apart from each other in a singlet or triplet state when close together, are coupled via a hyperfine interaction of one's electron's moment with the nuclear moment of another. What I think is that these terms are a combination of the 2$\times$2 Lennard-Jones potential and the magnetic energy (due to non-zero magnetic moment) term combined but would like to get a detailed picture of generating such a 2$\times$2 potential interaction.